# Function that gets a subdirectory of user-emacs-directory

Tags: directories

I remember reading about this function (it's part of Emacs) somewhere, but I can't for the life of me remember what it's called.

It takes a single argument `arg` (not sure if there's any more optional args)

- By default it looks for `(expand-file-name arg "~/")` and returns the path if it exists.
- If not, it looks for `(expand-file-name arg user-emacs-directory)` and returns the path if it exists.
- Otherwise, it creates the subdirectory in `user-emacs-directory` and returns the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`locate-user-emacs-file`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Standard-File-Names.html#Standard-File-Names).

---

Check out the below example code that,

- Creates `abc/` sub-directory under `user-emacs-directory` if `~/abc/` doesn't already exist.
- Always returns the full directory path, whether it got created or not.
- Displays a message in the event the directory did not get created for some reason.

```el
(let ((dir (locate-user-emacs-file "abc/")))
  (make-directory dir :parents)
  (when (not (file-directory-p dir))
    (message "%s directory was not created." dir))
  dir)
```

Comment: I can expand more on this answer when I get to a computer tomorrow.

Comment: Indeed I am. Looking forward to your elaboration.

Comment: btw this function will not create any sub-directories. The only directory it will create is `user-emacs-directory` if the OLD-NAME file does not exist.

Comment: Oh, that's a shame. That's the reason I was looking for it in the first place.

Comment: I couldn't try it now but it might be as simple as wrapping this function with `make-directory` with the second argument PARENTS set to `t`.

Comment: Sadly, `make-directory` returns `nil` if the directory wasn't created.

Comment: I hope I understood your question properly (because I got confused when you mentioned that there could be scenarios where a directory could not be created). I have updated the answer with example code with my understanding of your problem. If that's still not what you need, please update the question with more detail about your usecase.